# React with TS - Can't export Redux Devtools from window

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Here is the index.d.ts -

```
import { compose } from 'redux';

export { };

declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface ProcessEnv {
      readonly REACT_APP_API_PATH: string;
    }
  }

  let __REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__: typeof compose | undefined;

  interface Window {
    __REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__?: typeof compose;
  }
}
```

For some reason I can't export anything from it, I don't know why. New to React.
How can I solve that?

Comment: Don't bother, just use the [redux-devtools-extension](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension#13-use-redux-devtools-extension-package-from-npm) package instead, which is recommended when building with TypeScript. It has all the typings built in and gets rid of some ugly boilerplate.